# Process returned -11 (0x-b) after clicking "Speak" in pocketsphinx UI example

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I'm using an exact copy of the code from [here](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/gstreamer/).
Every time I run the code, the UI appears and things seem to be doing what they should. Except when I click the "Speak" button, it closes and the terminal prints out the following:

```
Process returned -11 (0x-b)
```

No errors appear. It closes as if it was meant to (I know it wasn't). Any idea on how to fix this?

(edit) Here's the complete code that I'm trying to execute

```
from gi import pygtkcompat
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

gst = Gst

print("Using pygtkcompat and Gst from gi")

pygtkcompat.enable()
pygtkcompat.enable_gtk(version='3.0')

import gtk

class DemoApp(object):
    """GStreamer/PocketSphinx Demo Application"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a DemoApp object"""
        self.init_gui()
        self.init_gst()

    def init_gui(self):
        """Initialize the GUI components"""
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.set_default_size(400,200)
        self.window.set_border_width(10)
        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        self.textbuf = gtk.TextBuffer()
        self.text = gtk.TextView(buffer=self.textbuf)
        self.text.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD)
        vbox.pack_start(self.text)
        self.button = gtk.ToggleButton("Speak")
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.button_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(self.button, False, False, 5)
        self.window.add(vbox)
        self.window.show_all()

    def init_gst(self):
        """Initialize the speech components"""
        self.pipeline = gst.parse_launch('autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert !  audioresample ! pocketsphinx ! fakesink')
        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect('message::element', self.element_message)

        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PAUSED)




    def element_message(self, bus, msg):
        """Receive element messages from the bus."""
        msgtype = msg.get_structure().get_name()
        if msgtype != 'pocketsphinx':
            return

        if msg.get_structure().get_value('final'):
            self.final_result(msg.get_structure().get_value('hypothesis'),
                msg.get_structure().get_value('confidence'))
            self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PAUSED)
            self.button.set_active(False)
        elif msg.get_structure().get_value('hypothesis'):
            self.partial_result(msg.get_structure().get_value('hypothesis'))

    def partial_result(self, hyp):
        """Delete any previous selection, insert text and select it."""
        # All this stuff appears as one single action
        self.textbuf.begin_user_action()
        self.textbuf.delete_selection(True, self.text.get_editable())
        self.textbuf.insert_at_cursor(hyp)
        ins = self.textbuf.get_insert()
        iter = self.textbuf.get_iter_at_mark(ins)
        iter.backward_chars(len(hyp))
        self.textbuf.move_mark(ins, iter)
        self.textbuf.end_user_action()

    def final_result(self, hyp, confidence):
        """Insert the final result."""
        # All this stuff appears as one single action
        self.textbuf.begin_user_action()
        self.textbuf.delete_selection(True, self.text.get_editable())
        self.textbuf.insert_at_cursor(hyp)
        self.textbuf.end_user_action()

    def button_clicked(self, button):
        """Handle button presses."""
        if button.get_active():
            button.set_label("Stop")
            self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PLAYING)
        else:
            button.set_label("Speak")
            self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PAUSED)

app = DemoApp()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer to get proper formatting. There is no guarantee this will work for you (or anyone else) !!!

I also upgraded it to full Gtk3.

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
#gi.require_version('GES', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gst#, GES
Gst.init(None)



class DemoApp(object):
    """GStreamer/PocketSphinx Demo Application"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a DemoApp object"""
        self.init_gui()
        self.init_gst()

    def init_gui(self):
        """Initialize the GUI components"""
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.set_default_size(400,200)
        self.window.set_border_width(10)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(expand = True)
        vbox.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.textbuf = Gtk.TextBuffer()
        self.text = Gtk.TextView(buffer=self.textbuf)
        self.text.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR)
        vbox.pack_start(self.text, True, True, 0)
        self.button = Gtk.ToggleButton("Speak")
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.button_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(self.button, False, False, 5)
        self.window.add(vbox)
        self.window.show_all()

    def init_gst(self):
        """Initialize the speech components"""
        #self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert !  audioresample ! pocketsphinx ! fakesink')
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect('message::element', self.element_message)

        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)




    def element_message(self, bus, msg):
        """Receive element messages from the bus."""
        msgtype = msg.get_structure().get_name()
        if msgtype != 'pocketsphinx':
            return

        if msg.get_structure().get_value('final'):
            self.final_result(msg.get_structure().get_value('hypothesis'),
                msg.get_structure().get_value('confidence'))
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
            self.button.set_active(False)
        elif msg.get_structure().get_value('hypothesis'):
            self.partial_result(msg.get_structure().get_value('hypothesis'))

    def partial_result(self, hyp):
        """Delete any previous selection, insert text and select it."""
        # All this stuff appears as one single action
        self.textbuf.begin_user_action()
        self.textbuf.delete_selection(True, self.text.get_editable())
        self.textbuf.insert_at_cursor(hyp)
        ins = self.textbuf.get_insert()
        iter = self.textbuf.get_iter_at_mark(ins)
        iter.backward_chars(len(hyp))
        self.textbuf.move_mark(ins, iter)
        self.textbuf.end_user_action()

    def final_result(self, hyp, confidence):
        """Insert the final result."""
        # All this stuff appears as one single action
        self.textbuf.begin_user_action()
        self.textbuf.delete_selection(True, self.text.get_editable())
        self.textbuf.insert_at_cursor(hyp)
        self.textbuf.end_user_action()

    def button_clicked(self, button):
        """Handle button presses."""
        if button.get_active():
            button.set_label("Stop")
            #self.pipeline.set_mode(GES.PipelineFlags.RENDER)
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        else:
            button.set_label("Speak")
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)

app = DemoApp()
Gtk.main()
```

Other notes:

(1 when I run your original code I get a Segmentation Fault. I suspect your OS is returning a signal -11 instead of segfaulting. Searching Google for Gst.State.PLAYING Segmentation Fault gets a lot of interesting results.

(2 I have no experience in GStreamer, so I can't help you a lot on this problem. I just thought I would post my results and my 2 cents.

(3 Some of this code comes from https://github.com/pitivi/gst-editing-services/issues/39

Comment: Also checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227738/python3-error-with-gstreamer).

Comment: ValueError: Namespace GES not available

Comment: from gi.require_version('GES', '1.0')

Comment: Well thanks to your code, I was able to get further than clicking the "Speak" button, but oddly it's not recording. Pulseaudio shows no devices recording, no matter the state of the button and no text appears.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't help you more. You could post a new question explaining your problem, @Vindicium

Comment: Well you've helped a lot so far. Thanks for that. The original problem was the "Speak" button issue and that's been solved, so I'll go ahead and mark this answer as the solution. This is one of those projects that has one error after another and it's irritating lol. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to be of help @Vindicium